# Center images while maintaining responsive design

Tags: css

I'd like to push the three icons below towards the center of the page while still retaining a responsive layout.

Is `display: grid;` or `display: row;` more suitable?

And depending on your answer, what are the cleanest properties to apply?

[image]

```
<html>    
<div id="contact">
  <h1>Let's connect.</h1>
  <div id="image-holder">
  <div id="github-div">
    <a href="https://github.com/klin-nj-97" target="_blank" id="profile-link">
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/25/25231.svg" alt="github" class="contact-img">
  </a>
    </div>
    <div id="linkedin-div">
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/kevin-lin-33085a133/" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin" class="contact-img">
  </a>
    </div>
    <div id="email-div">
  <a href="mailto:kevin_lin@brown.edu">
    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/email-envelope-outline-shape-with-rounded-corners_318-49938.jpg" alt="email" class="contact-img">
  </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</html>


<style>
#contact h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 75px;
  padding-bottom: 55px;
}
#image-holder {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  margin-left: 
}
#contact a{
  color: white;
}
.contact-img {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be use this simple trick.

Please give `align-items: center; justify-content: center;` into `#image-holder`

For more details Go to [display:flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Hope this help.

Let me know further clarifications.

```css
#contact h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 75px;
  padding-bottom: 55px;
}
#image-holder {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#contact a{
  color: white;
}
.contact-img {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>    
<div id="contact">
  <h1>Let's connect.</h1>
  <div id="image-holder">
  <div id="github-div">
    <a href="https://github.com/klin-nj-97" target="_blank" id="profile-link">
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/25/25231.svg" alt="github" class="contact-img">
  </a>
    </div>
    <div id="linkedin-div">
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/kevin-lin-33085a133/" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin" class="contact-img">
  </a>
    </div>
    <div id="email-div">
  <a href="mailto:kevin_lin@brown.edu">
    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/email-envelope-outline-shape-with-rounded-corners_318-49938.jpg" alt="email" class="contact-img">
  </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Gotcha, thank you - do you know why `align-items: center; justify-content: center;` isn't working for this other page? 
https://codepen.io/klin-nj-97/pen/NLPrez

Comment: You need to   `align-items: center; justify-content: center;`  into `.glove-feature`

Comment: Gotcha, that worked. So how come for the original `align-items: center; justify-content: center;` could be applied to the parent container `#image-holder` but now it had to be applied to the child `.glove-feature`?

Comment: And looking at it now, adding `align-items: center; justify-content: center;` into `.glove-feature` doesn't completely center the images and descriptions. It is still to the left of the center.

Comment: Please see again, I will be add `.glove-feature {align-items: center;}` And it's Working perfectly.

Comment: And According to your html structure you need to use `align-items: center; justify-content: center;` both of your div (parent and child).  Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Add the property `justify-content: center;` to the `#image-holder` id.

The buttons will be centered.

Code below

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oey37tvp/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this is to:

1. Use class-based selectors instead of ID selectors
2. Use flexbox to centre the layout (and text) horizontally, and centre the layout vertically

I've changed your HTML to use class-based selectors instead of IDs, e.g. `class="contact"` instead of `id="contact"`:

```
<div class="contact">
  <h1 class="contact__title">Let's connect.</h1>

  <div class="contact__images">
    <a class="contact__link" href="https://github.com/klin-nj-97" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/25/25231.svg" alt="github" class="contact__icon">
    </a>

    <a class="contact__link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/kevin-lin-33085a133/" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin" class="contact__icon">
    </a>

    <a class="contact__link" href="mailto:kevin_lin@brown.edu">
      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/email-envelope-outline-shape-with-rounded-corners_318-49938.jpg" alt="email" class="contact__icon">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

For the cleanest CSS, it's ideal that all your selectors have the same level of specificity, and the best way to do that is use only class-based selectors. This will let you override styles more easily. You can read more about CSS specificity [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

The following CSS uses flexbox to position your content accordingly, assuming you are trying to centre everything vertically within the page:

```
body {
  margin: 0; /* browser adds margins by default */
}

.contact {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center; /* centers your content horizontally */
  align-items: center; /* centers your content vertically */
  height: 100vh;
}

.contact__title {
  margin: 0 0 55px; /* if you have a header you'd like to account for, the first value can be the header height */
}

.contact__images {
  /* you don't even need anything here but the wrapping div of this classname is required to keep your icons aligned */
}

.contact__link {
  text-decoration: none; /* proper way to hide the text link underline */
}

.contact__icon {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

The CSS class naming convention I used is called BEM. I recommend reading more about it if you are interested in writing clean CSS. You can do so [here](http://getbem.com/) or [here](https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/).

I have a working example [here on CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xagEbg/?editors=1100). You can change the height of the page to see it's centred vertically.